# Wish to understand an AC motor electrical diagram schematic to safely connect a capacitor and switch

Tags: capacitor, wiring, ac-motor

I have this motor (Samsung Electronics SMV-260UA) diagram and a 10 μF capacitor from a salvaged microwave:

[image: wiring schematic]
[image: cap]

I've experimented with supplying power, but I need start up current to kick the motor into action. I found a capacitor I believe is correctly rated.

This will be connected to an AC switch (toggle) and have a hot, ground, and neutral available. The capacitor should go where the C is in the diagram. But what is the correct wiring from the switch to make sure this is properly wired? The motor cord has purple, white, blue, orange and red wires.

[image: full motor]
[image: cord]

Comment: Keep (protective) earth connected all the time. Switch hot. Where possible, switch neutral, too. I'm a bit confused to see both H and L drawn as *connected*. (Is that a blower?)

Comment: Yes, it's a fan from a microwave.

Comment: H and L are probably windings 180° apart...

Comment: I note that your motor says 1.25 A while your capacitor says 0.83 A.

Comment: @jonathanjo good catch, I couldn't easily find one identical, so I went with 220V and missed the amps. That is a problem correct? I need a proper one?

Comment: @kruemi `windings 180° apart`? One interpretation was High and Low speed - funny they should be paralleled (minimal loss/ max efficiency?).

Comment: I'm  not sure it it is high/low speed or 180°. I can't tell until I put power to one or the other (H or L) right?

Comment: @greybeard I guess, the high / low idea is better than the 180° one. I'd go with that one. It makes much more sense.

Comment: `[motor current 1,25 A, capacitor .85 A] is a problem correct?` No. In all likelihood, motor current is specified through all of 2-3 windings, but the current through the main/ *run* winding doesn't flow through the capacitor (as does that through auxiliary/ *start* windings).

Comment: Are there improvements I could make to this to help others find it useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the schematic which is self explanatory.

[image]

Comment: Are L and H exclusive or are they both connected at the same time for high speed?

Comment: I'd recommend switching neutral as well.

Comment: @kruemi - Hi, Only 'Lo'  for low speed and only 'Hi' for high speed.

Comment: @vu2nan It looks to me like you connect L and H at the same time, per the diagram in the motor photo.  I'm sure you're right that connecting one of them would work, but I'll guess that one at a time is  low speed, both connected gives high speed.

Comment: @jonathanjo - Hi, Please check this out https://www.diyforums.net/microwave-fan-motor-wiring-137312.html.

Comment: @vu2nan it's possible of course, but I'd trust the diagram from the manufacturer, showing both connected, over a DIY forum post.  For whatever it's worth, a [video](https://youtu.be/lQnB0YvcH7U?t=249) shows someone using one with just the violet "L" wire connected.

Comment: Thank you, jonathanjo.